# Understanding of Example of Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

**Theorem**
Suppose $\,f\left( a,b\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\,$ is differentiable. Then $f'$ satisfies the intermediate value theorem.

**Example**
$$f\left( x\right) =\begin{cases} 1,x\leq 0\\ 0,x>0\end{cases}$$
We know that there is no $g$ such that $g\hspace{0.1ex}'\left( x\right)=f\left( x\right)$.

---

Note that I did not understand really what this example is meaning. Can you explain? How is the theorem related to the example?

Comment: He is saying $f$ does not have intermediate value property...

Comment: That is [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), and the point is that it does *not* require the derivate to be continuous. – But I don't see how your example is related, because it is not differentiable.

Comment: @MartinR The assertion is that $f$ is not a derivative.

Comment: @DanielFischer: You are right. I was assuming that $f$ in the example is $f$ from the theorem. My fault.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, that switch caught me too.

Comment: @cello   **Theorem** says $f$ is diff. Yet, $f$ is not diff. in the example. Is there is a absurd stiation?

Comment: @DanielFischer Theorem says $f$ is diff. Yet, $f$ is not diff. in the example. Is there is a absurd stiation?

Comment: @hayyam The two "$f$" are in different scopes, they don't refer to the same thing. Call the function in the theorem $h$.

Comment: @DanielFischer **Remark.** Suppose $f\left( a,b\right) \rightarrow R$ is differentiable. Suppose $f$ has no local extremum, then $f$ is strictly monotone.  Since $f$ no local extreme, $f^{'}\left( x\right) \neq 0$  for all $x \in\left( a,b\right)$. This should imply that $f^{'}\left( x\right) >0$ for all $x \in \left( a,b\right)$ or $f^{'}\left( x\right) <0$ for all $x \in \left( a,b\right)$                                                                                                                                  My question is that how is the theorem related to the remark?

Comment: The idea is probably "The derivative $f'$ has the intermediate value property. If there were points $\xi,\eta \in (a,b)$ with $f'(\xi) < 0 < f'(\eta)$, by the intermediate value property there would be point $\zeta\in (a,b)$ with $f'(\zeta) = 0$". **But** it's actually more complicated than that, it does _not_ follow that $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x\in (a,b)$ if $f$ has no local extreme. Consider $f(x) = x^3$ on $(-1,1)$. However, if a function is not strictly monotone, it follows that it has local extrema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The theorem is [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)):

> Let $f:(a, b) \to \Bbb R$ be differentiable. Then $f'$ has the intermediate
>   value property: If $a < c < d < b$ then for all $y$ between $f'(c)$
>   and $f'(d)$ there is a $x$ between $c$ and $d$ such that $f'(x) = y$.

(This does not follow from the [intermediate value theorem for continuous
functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), because it does not require that $f'$ is continuous.)

The function $F: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ in your example (renamed to avoid
confusion)
$$
F\left( x\right) =\begin{cases} 1, &x\leq 0\\ 0, &x>0\end{cases}
$$
does *not* have the intermediate value property: $F(-1) = 1$,
$F(1) = 0$, but there is no $x$ such that $F(x) = \frac 12$.

It follows from Darboux's theorem that there is no differentiable
function $f$ such that $f' = F$.

Comment: @hayyam: You are welcome!